How to integrate ZKTecho wl-20 with node js?
I have tried to integrate with zklib library but it throwing this error
{
data: ,
err: Error: TIME OUT !! 1 PACKETS REMAIN !
at Timeout. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\node-zklib-master\zklibtcp.js:282:17)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I was using node -zklib library but i am not able to get any data from that
